# MVC 3 checkbox always returns true, even if unchecked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have the following code

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Defaults)
    {
        <tr class="CertainCategory">
            <td>
                @item.Item1
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Use)
                @Html.Hidden("guid", guid.guid.ToString())
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I'm trying to use AJAX to submit form values to the controller method. My problem is that the value of the checkbox is always sent as `true`.

```
$('.CropUsageItem').each(function () {

            var guid = $(this).find("#guid").val();
            var chk = $(this).find("#use").val();
            var data = {
                guid: guid,
                chk: chk
            };

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "DefaultValues/SaveDefault",
                data: data
            });
        });
```

I have searched StackOverflow with similar results but none of them fully apply to my scenario. How can I send the correct value?

Comment: Your saying `var chk = $(this).find("#use").val();` `chk` equals true regardless of the checked status of `#use` ?

Comment: Yes, even if its unchecked it still posts true to the action method

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the following verify if a checkbox is checked.

```
var chk = $('#use').attr('checked');
```

or

```
var chk = $('#use').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Brilliant! the second option does exactly what i was after.

Comment: @Heinrich - Glad to help, you may wish to use fiddler2 to help you debug these sort of issues.

Comment: first option returns always 'checked', no matter what :)

Comment: second option is the answer for me

Comment: in my case first option is always undefined, but second works like a charm

Answer (score 7):

.val() returns the contents of the value attribute. as it probably is non-null that equates to true.

Also check your casing. JavaScript, css & therefor also jQuery are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Like Simon said, .val() returns the value attribute of the checkbox, which can be any value you want. But more specifically, it returns the value *property* of the DOM object, which is initialized by the attribute. MVC seems to set the value to "true" by default, which seems pretty meaningless to me. But in some cases you might want want to set it to an ID or some other meaningful value for the checked option as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621324/jquery-val-and-checkboxes) points out.

Nicholas provided one good way of getting whether the checkbox is checked above.  Check and uncheck the checkbox on this jsfiddle for an example of the various approaches and their results:

**[JQuery Checkbox Checked](http://jsfiddle.net/9ygumyy9/2/)**

---

Summary of fiddle:

```
$("#use").val();  //Returns the value. Not related to checked state.
$("#use").attr("checked")  //Returns the checked attribute value. Does not change with checked state.
$("#use").prop("checked")  //Returns boolean checked state.
$("#use")[0].checked       //Returns boolean checked state.
$("#use").is(":checked")   //Returns boolean checked state.
```

Notice the results of .val and .attr do not change. That is because the val property is not dependent on the checked state, and the actual checked attribute in the markup does not update when the checkbox changes. Only the property on the DOM object behind the scenes, which is what the last three methods access.

---

See jQuery's API [documentation on .prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chk = $('#use').checked;
```

worked for me