# How to validate when a checkbox is checked in AngularJS e2e tests?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I've been trying out the [AngularJS e2e tests](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) and am getting stuck determining whether or not a checkbox is checked.

I used the end to end test for the [checkbox input](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox) as a sample (see the *End to end test* tab in the *Example*).

**Html snippet:**

`Value1: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1"> <br/>`

**Controller snippet:**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = true;
}
```

**Here is what I tried:**

1) `expect(binding('value1')).toEqual('true');`

This works in the sample end to end test as long as `value1` is displayed on screen with `{{value1}}`. If you test this locally and remove `{{value1}} the binding test fails. In most of my real-world examples I am not displaying the checkbox value on the screen anywhere.

2) `expect(input('value1').val()).toEqual('true');`

The value will always default to `on` and is not related to whether or not the checkbox is in a checked state (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5621324/1207991)).

---

**Note:** It looks like the Angular E2E testing will be replaced with [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) in the future (see [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I upvoted this question as I had the same issue.
I used following workaround in my test, but I'm hoping to see the better way.

```
expect( element('input[ng-model="value1"]').attr('checked') ).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this better than what I'm currently doing. I'll keep this question open a bit just in case there is a better way :)

Comment: In karma, it's not `attr` but `prop` that should be used. For fellow googlers.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. The Leo Gallucci answer works.

Answer (score 55):

For anyone using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor), there is webdriver [isSelected()](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) for exactly this.

Instead of asking for `checked` attribute you can do:

```
expect(element(by.model('value1')).isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: When i try this code getting Exception : "invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated". Any idea how to solve this

Comment: Back in my Protractor days, I solved the Stale element problem with the [waitReady.js](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb) script, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533139/protractor-correct-use-of-waitready-js-file-in-my-tests/35536164

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping there is a better way but I got around this by validating the count of the checked input elements matching that model binding:

`expect(element('input[ng-model="value1"]:checked').count()).toBe(1);`

At least one downside to this when checking if something is not checked is if the element doesn't exist or if there was a typo the value would still be 0 like in this example:

`expect(element('input[ng-model="valueDoesNotExist"]:checked').count()).toBe(0);`