# Protractor get element by model in repeater array

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

For example, in HTML page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <td ng-click="activePost(post)" class="title">{{post.title}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(post)">Delete</button></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="post.active" 
        id="{{post.id}}" /></td>
 </tr>
```

Then, I want something like:

```
element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).then(function(posts) {
   var activePost = posts[0].element(by.model('active'));
   expect(activePost).toEqual(true);
});
```

This returns an unable to find element. I am basing this on this question and answer: 
[Protractor find element inside a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757340/protractor-find-element-inside-a-repeater)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value passed into `by.model()` should be as is on the page:

```
var activePost = posts[0].element(by.model('post.active'));
```

Note that `activePost` variable would refer to an element, hence even if it's value would be `false` (unchecked checkbox), the `expect(activePost).toEqual(true);` expectation would be met. You need to [assert the checkbox's value instead using `isSelected()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25715341/771848):

```
expect(activePost.isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
```