# Protractor: Correct use of waitReady.js file in my tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

We are using browser.wait extensively throughout the entire test suite. It became a headache when managing different timeouts for different scenarios. I came across a waitReady function(https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb), but I am unable to utilize it in my code.
The directory looks like: (all files besides each other)
.

```
├── conf.js
├── main.js
├── waitReady.js
```

Main.js --->Contains all describe and it blocks

```
    require('./waitReady.js');
    describe(...){
    it{
    code...
expect(element.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
    };
    });
```

For some reason the code does not find that function and my code keeps getting function not defined error. Do I need to initialize it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the import into the `onPrepare()` in your protractor config:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    require('./waitReady.js');
},
```

Comment: I am using this statement for the waitready check expect(element(by.binding('message'))).waitReady().toBeTruthy();

Comment: When running the tests I am getting an error:
Failed : expect(...).waitReady is not a function

Is there anything I am missing out on?

Comment: @cathelesup yeah, but `waitReady()` should not be called on `expect()` - it should be called on an `ElementFinder` - the result of `element`.

Comment: Works for me now, I was doing it the wrong way before. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

I had no doubt Alecxe would answer this one :)

An alternate solution for managing timeout lengths, which I've found useful, is to add default timeout lengths to a basePage, or onPrepare. For this I use t-shirt sizes... Eg:

```
this.timeout = {
    's' : 500,
    'm'  : 1000,
    'l'  : 5000,
    'xl'  : 10000
};
```

Then call thusly:

```
browser.wait(someThingToWaitFor(), this.timeout.xl);
```

Comment: Brine: this is a great answer as well, although I do not want to explicitly mention wait times, I want it to be dynamic..less guessing.