# How to check multiple checkboxes in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, protractor

I've seen how to check one checkbox via this link: 
[How to validate when a checkbox is checked in AngularJS e2e tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485217/how-to-validate-when-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-angularjs-e2e-tests)

However I would like to know how to do this to check if all checkboxes that I have on my view are going to be checked.

At the moment the code below only checks if one checkbox has been selected:

```
    .clickElementById('user-' + data.userIndex)
    .expect(
        element('input[ng-model="user.checked"]')
        .attr('checked')
    ).toBeTruthy()
```

Which is what I want however when I go onto my next test of selecting all checkboxes via a button I would like to loop through all of the checkboxes to test if they have been selected. Apologies to repeat myself.

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.all` which creates an array of the specified elements and then you can either loop or call them directly i.e.

```
element.all(by.model('user.checked').then(function(btn) {
    expect(btn[0].attr('checked')).toBe('true');
});
```

Or with the loop

```
element.all(by.model('user.checked').each(function(btn) {
     // iterates through each btn
     expect(btn.attr('checked')).toBe('true');
});
```

source: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

Comment: To add to this you can actually use the each method that comes with protractor. Simple by replacing the then promise.

Comment: Ah true!  I forgot about `.each()` - much better than the for loop.  I updated my answer.

Comment: if you use `by.css` then you can use `isSelected`. Just another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also *[reduce](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce)* it to a single check - all checkboxes are checked or not:

```
var allChecked = element.all(by.model('user.checked')).reduce(function(acc, btn) {
    return btn.getAttribute('checked')).then(function(checked) {
        return acc && (checked == 'true');
    });
}, true);
expect(allChecked).toBe(true);
```