# Checkbox value always returns "on"?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to return the value of a checkbox to enable and disable a button.
Making the checkbox is not a problem, the problem is the check box value always returns on. How should I get a value indicating if the checkbox is checked?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> <label>Do you agree  </label><br />
    <input type="button" value="Continue" id="button" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    var checkboxValue = $(this).val();
    alert(checkboxValue);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried $(this).is(':checked') ?

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value, use .is(':checked')

Comment: Everyone knows how to get the value but nobody has mentioned why it returns `on`.  That confused that tar out of me, too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)('checked');

```
var checkboxValue = $(this).prop('checked');
```

Comment: @gdoron, We're using jQuery. How is prop('checked') not valid and/or inferior?

Comment: @gdoron if you already have the jQuery framework loaded, why not use it? The overhead will be minimal and it will keep the code consistent in my opinion. Further, should you encounter a future browser that doens't support this.checked (for some bizzare reason), you could expect a framework update to handle this for you. All IMHO.

Comment: @mkumpan, The same as why `$('selector').each(function(){$(this).css('display', 'block');})` is bad, yes it does the job but you could have done it simply with  `$('selector').show()`

Comment: @MohamedSamir, you probably misspelled `checked` or used it in a bad context.

Comment: @gdoron, let's not be mixing mice and elephants here. As RemarkLima mentioned, I was gunning for code consistency. The framework flexibility remark is also quite valid, albeit much less likely to fire.

Comment: for me this always returns undefined

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you need `checked`

```
var checkboxValue = this.checked;
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things is going on here

1. the check box as is does not have a value
2. you should be checking to see if its checked or not

try this

```
$('#checkBox').prop('checked');
```

if its checked you should get back true and false if its not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using (If you're using jQuery 1.6+):

```
var checkboxValue = $(this).prop('checked');
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

This should return a `true` or `false` correctly.

Comment: @gdoron if you already have the jQuery framework loaded, why not use it? The overhead will be minimal and it will keep the code consistent in my opinion. Further, should you encounter a future browser that doens't support `this.checked` (for some bizzare reason), you could expect a framework update to handle this for you. All IMHO.

Comment: `prop('checked')` will use `this.checked` so if it doesn't work, so as jQuery. and how exactly writing more makes you code better? jquery shouldn't be replacing vanilla js.

Comment: @gdoron I disagree, but that's the joys of a free world right? Personally I'm of the opinion, if you're going to use a framework, use it as much as possible simply for consistency. A better method of `this.checked` could appear, and you then have to refactor all your code. Or just change the framework to suit. No?

Answer (score 1):

Or what about making use of the [`:checked` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)?

```
$(this).is(':checked') // returns true if checked and false otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *is(':checked')* instead of *.val*

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    var checkboxValue = $(this).is(':checked');
    alert(checkboxValue);
});
```

It returns true or false

See also 
[jQuery val() and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621324/jquery-val-and-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to do this, no jquery, based off of @gdoron's answer.

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        //Whatever u want to do if checked
    }
    else {
        //Whatever u want to do if not checked
    }
})
```

Try checking/unchecking the checkbox in the below snippet to see this in action...

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            //Whatever u want to do if checked
            alert("u check");
        }
        else {
            //Whatever u want to do if not checked
            alert("u uncheck");
        }
    })
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Coconuts?
```

Comment: The problem with your checkbox is that "value" returns whether or not the input is disabled/active/being used. To get what you want, you must use `.checked` or `.prop('checked')` instead. Both of these return true/false. I recommend using `.checked`, but use what is easiest for you.

Comment: Also by the way, for users who already have jquery loaded `.prop('checked')` is easiest as it is already included in jquery and fully cross-browser. `.checked` is just for those who don't want to use jquery...